# Can't complete directxtk installation

Tags: visual-studio-2022, directxtk

I am trying to add the directxtk Project to Visual Studio 2022, i followed this guide: https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DirectXTK#adding-to-a-vs-solution, i choose the "DirectXTK_Desktop_2022" Project, add it to my Solution then i go to Properties but i don't have the "Common Properties > References" menu:
[image]

Instead i have this:
[image]

Comment: You're probably getting stuck on a setup step for UWP/XBox projects, which don't apply for a Win32 desktop app, to quote from the guide: _"For a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app or Xbox One solution, you may need to set Reference Assembly Output to false since DirectXTK is a static C++ library and not a WinRT component."_

Comment: Yes, you're right! idiot am i. Thanks.